# Set conditional on template based on referring page slug

Tags: wp-query, query, conditional-tags

I have a portion of a page template that is conditional upon the following `elseif`

```
<?php elseif( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['details'] ) &&  $wp_query->query_vars['details'] == 'child':
```

Is there a way to exclude a queries from a particular page slug? I would like to exclude queries coming from a page called `services-we-provide`.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
 && !$wp_query->query_vars('pagename=services-we-provide')
```

**EDIT:**
I guess another thing I could do is add a `elseif` before the one above that looks to see if you're coming from the services-we-provide page...is that possible, if so, how would I go about that?

**EDIT 2:**
A little more research and I foudn that this is usually done with a referrer. I found this javascript, however I'm unclear how / where to implement and how to reference in the `elseif` statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163851/745514

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using the [`wp-get-referer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer) function in a conditional. Here's the resulting code:

```
<?php
    $ref1 = parse_url(wp_get_referer()); //getting the referring URL
    if($ref1["path"]=='/services-we-provide/')
:?>
    //Do stuff
<?php else: ?>
    //Do other stuff
<?php endif ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query does not exclude post objects based on title (using the post__not_in => array() parameter), rather based on its ID. So you would need to do another WP_Query, get_posts, or direct query on the database to obtain the post ID from title and use it on the WP_Query.